# Find all edge self-avoiding path of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In Mathematica, we can use `FindPath[graph, start, end, Infinity, All]` to find all self-avoiding paths, which means the path can not cross vertex and edge repeatedly.

[image]

Drawing code as follows:

```
v = Graphics[{GrayLevel[1], EdgeForm[RGBColor[0, 0, 0]], Disk[{0, 0}]}];
G4 = GridGraph[{4, 4}, VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexShape -> v, ImageSize -> 640, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[i, Center], {i, 16}]];
paths = FindPath[G4, 1, 16, Infinity, All];
ArrowedGraph[graph_, path_] := HighlightGraph[
    graph, (*Rule@@@Partition[path,2,1]*){},
    Prolog -> {Blue, Thickness[.003], Arrowheads[Table[.03, 15]], Arrow[BSplineCurve[GraphEmbedding[graph][[path]], SplineDegree -> 2]]}
]
ArrowedGraph[G4, RandomChoice@paths]
```

It can find all the 184 self-avoiding paths.

---

**Edge self-avoiding path** allow passes through the same point multiple times, but the edges cannot be repeated.

For example, the path `{1, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 6, 10, 11, 12, 8, 7, 11, 15, 16}` is a legal edge self-avoiding path, but not a legal self-avoiding path.

[image]

How to find all such paths?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A013990, 800 solutions for 4 × 4

Answer (score 5):

Using `FindPath` on `LineGraph[G4]` with all pairs of edges where the first edge in each pair is incident to `1` and the second incident to `16`:

```
edgepairs = Tuples[Map[EdgeIndex[G4, #] &] /@ (IncidenceList[G4, #] & /@ {1, 16})];
epaths = FindPath[LineGraph[G4], ##, Infinity, All]&@@@edgepairs;
```

Using only the first pair of edges incident to vertices `1` and `16`:

```
eapaths1 = FindPath[LineGraph[G4], ##, Infinity, All] & @@ edgepairs[[1]];

ArrowedGraph[G4, Flatten[List @@@ EdgeList[G4][[RandomChoice@eapaths1]]]]
```

[image]

---

However, we see that not all paths are legal.

The function `decoder` can filter out the legal path.

```
ArrowedGraph[graph_, path_] := HighlightGraph[
    graph, (*Rule@@@Partition[path,2,1]*){},
    Prolog -> {Blue, Thickness[.003], Arrowheads[Table[.03, 15]], Arrow[BSplineCurve[GraphEmbedding[graph][[path]], SplineDegree -> 2]]}
]
direction[{a_\[UndirectedEdge]b_, c_\[UndirectedEdge]d_}] := If[Count[{a, b, c, d}, a] == 2, b -> a, a -> b]
decoder[path_] := Block[
    {dpath = direction /@ Partition[EdgeList[G4][[path]], 2, 1]},
    If[dpath[[1, 1]] != 1 || dpath[[-1, -1]] != 16, Return[Nothing]];
    If[dpath[[2 ;; -1, + 1]] != dpath[[1 ;; -2, -1]], Return[Nothing]];
    Append[First /@ dpath, 16]
]
v = Graphics[{GrayLevel[1], EdgeForm[RGBColor[0, 0, 0]], Disk[{0, 0}]}];
G4 = GridGraph[{4, 4}, VertexSize -> 0.2, VertexShape -> v, ImageSize -> 640, VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[i, Center], {i, 16}], EdgeLabels -> "Index"]
L4 = LineGraph[G4, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
edgepairs = Tuples[Map[EdgeIndex[G4, #]&] /@ (IncidenceList[G4, #]& /@ {1, 16})];
epaths = Flatten[FindPath[L4, ##, Infinity, All]& @@@ edgepairs, 1];
Length[vpath = decoder /@ RandomChoice[epaths, 10000]]
ArrowedGraph[G4, #]& /@ vpath
```

But this function is so inefficient that it can't run through all the solutions.

Comment: `Flatten[List @@@ EdgeList[G4][[path]]]` -> `Prepend[First @@@ (EdgeList[G4][[path]]), 1]`, and seems need remove the paths which starts from `2` and `5`

Comment: @GalAster, good points. Looks like more processing is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I am under the impression that edge self-avoiding paths are essentially self-avoiding paths in the *dual graph*.

Should that be true, you could generate the dual graph with the function `IGDualGraph` from Szabolcs' package `` "IGraphM`" `` and run `FindPath` on it. The only problem is that the end points of these paths will be edges. So, to obtain all edge self-avoiding paths from vertex `i` to vertex `j`, you have to find all self-avoiding paths in the dual graph between those edges that are incident to `i` and `j`, respectively.